# cant install discord.js in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I am a new programmer and I don't really understand that much in node.js or any of these things.
My main problem isn't a code bug itself rather not being able to install discord.js in Visual Studio Code.

The command I tried to run is "npm install discord.js" in the terminal and in cmd but both didn't work for me.

The output:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\unique-filename\package.json
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\unique-filename\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dezkah\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-11T14_35_47_984Z-debug.log
```

I did install the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Sorry if this question is stupid or something but I can't seem to find a solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your package.js does not have a `main` property. it should be something like `"main": "index.js"`

Comment: Im pretty sure it does

```{
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Did you save your package.json? I was able to use your package.json file and install discord.js without an issue.

Comment: How do you save it? I am pretty sure I did save it When I open vsCode I can see the package.json

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to after selecting an empty folder in vscode as worskpace is open a terminal, write and follow instructions

```sh
npm init
```

or `npm init --yes` for insert all default values.

this generate a package.json inside your working folder.

After that you can install packages via npm

```
npm i discord.js --save
```

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that but I have done 
```npm init```
and still it doesn't work :(

Comment: are you opening your terminal inside your project root?

Comment: Yes but I did try with a command prompt but same thing and output.

Comment: I think that the problem has to do something with my "main entry" in the package.json file but I have a file with the same name as the main entry

Comment: there is a `node_modules` folder in your project root folder? if yes, delete it, reinstall depenedencies with `npm install` and retry to install discord.js with `npm install discord.js  --save`.

Comment: @Sasson I have copied and pasted your package.json inside an empty folder, runned npm install and npm install discord.js and it worked without problems. So i don't think is a package.json related problem

Comment: There is nothing in the folder except index.js and and package.json
I think its related to node.js

Answer (score 0):

[image: installing discord.j]

It's working fine on Windows OS. I created a new `package.json` file and then installed `discord.js`.

Will you please clear the cache and then try again?

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then try to install `discord.js` again:

```
npm i discord.js
```

Comment: For some reason even this command doesn't work on my cmd.
https://prnt.sc/ux6sb8